# UWP Combobox scrollbar visibility

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I have items in my combox which it can accommodate or sometimes can not accommodate. For each case i want to show the scroll bar. But i can see the scrollbar goes away after few seconds. Can we show it always -

```
<ComboBox x:Name="VComboBox" x:Uid="VComboBox" SelectionChanged="OnVComboBoxSelectionChanged" Margin="8,0,8,8" Width="160" ItemsSource="{x:Bind BandCollections}">
  <ComboBox.Header>
     <TextBlock x:Name="VBandHeader" x:Uid="VBandHeader" Text="Pass" Foreground="Black"/>
  </ComboBox.Header>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: This built-in animation doesn't actually hide the scrollbar, but only makes it smaller so that it doesn't obscure the content and looks cleaner. As it is part of the design language of Windows 10, it would be more appropriate to keep the default behavior instead of changing it.Is there a specific reason to why you want it always visible in expanded state?

Comment: My app is running on an touch screen. It feels bit disturbing to touch on item to get back the scrollbar.